# regex find all word not end with "=" or " ="

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

i want to find all words that start with @ and not end with equal (=)

```
"@parameter" ---> result = "@parameter"
"@parameter = @first" ---> result = "@first"
"@parameter = @first, @parameter = @second" ---> result = "@first" and "@second"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you want to find `@first` in your third example?

Answer (score 1):

Use regex `@\w+\b(?!\s*=)`, which means looking for `@` followed by some word which is not followed by `=` (with optional leading space characters)

Answer (score 0):

Use a greedy quantifier until end of line and backtrack searching for an optional `=`, with:

```
 ^.*=?\s*(@\w+)\s*$
```